# Проблемы асинхронности ООП

Tags: c#, ооп

Я имею main класс, и имею другой класс с получением html. Когда происходит асинхронное выполнение, программа перестает выводить что-то в консоль
Вот мэин

```
class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            a1 class1 = new a1();
            class1.Hot();
        }
    }
```

Вот класс

```
 class a1
    {
        public async void Hot()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://....");
            Console.WriteLine("a");
         }
     }
```

Comment: Вообще то вы html не выводите совсем никуда, а только `a`.

Comment: @Bulson я специально `а` поставил, чтобы видно было, что после асинхронности он перестает работать

Comment: Добавьте в конец Main()  `Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: При вызове метода `Hot` тоже надо поставить `await`: `await class1.Hot();`

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Вопрос тот-же, что и к отвечающему, как вы планируете ожидать `void`?

Comment: Написав полностью идентичный код, у меня, почему-то, всё работает исправно https://imgur.com/JswlZcD

Comment: @Arasfon Наверно потому, что вы пишете это в программе, где нету окна, а лишь вывод?) У автора (как правильно подметили выше) скорей всего попросту закрывается окно консоли сразу из за чего он думает, что нет вывода.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да, окно действительно закрывается до того как операция заканчивается, а вместо `Console.ReadLine();` можно было бы изменить `void` на `Task` и сделать `await class1.Hot();`

Comment: @Arasfon `Task` подчеркивает красным, нету ссылки на сборку пишет. Прописал `Console.ReadLine();` в конце, так же не помогает

Comment: У меня дальше идет парсинг страницы. И он так быстро бы не завершался => можно сделать вывод, что после await ничего не происходит, никаких действий, он просто завершается

Comment: @Arasfon Поменял класс на Task, Помогло, спасибо

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я не очень понял вопрос. `await` корректно работает с методами, возвращающими как `Task`/`ValueTask`, так и `void`.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko [Уверены](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orMgA.png)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, в документации написано вот это: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, хотя да, вы правы. Я ответил на другой вопрос. `void` метод может быть `async`, но это не значит, что его можно вызывать через `await`.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko `void` можно пометить как `async`, он выполнит внутри себя все необходимое асинхронно, но его невозможно дождаться, невозможно ему присвоить `await`. Вы же (как и автор ответа) советуете указать `await` и дожидаться `void`, что невозможно. И это мне как бы непонятно, вот и спрашиваю, как вы будете его ждать?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, как я уже написал, я ошибся и уже это признал. :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы не дожидаетесь завершения асинхронного вызова, напишите await перед вызовом асинхронного метода:

```cs
class Program
{
     static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
     {
         a1 class1 = new a1();
         await class1.Hot();
    }
}
```

Возвращаемый тип асинхронной функции должен быть `Task`

```
public async Task Hot()
{
            Console.WriteLine("a");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://....");
            Console.WriteLine("a");
}
```

Ссылки по теме:

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: А как вы дождетесь `void`? Нате вам [подсказку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orMgA.png)

Comment: Вы правы сейчас дополню ответ